# Why is UserManager.CreateIdentityAsync() looking for IdentityRole and how to fix?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6, asp.net-identity

I'm using **Identity2.0** with **MVC5** *CodeFirst* I have extended both the `IdentityUser` and `IdentityRole` like this:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

public class ApplicationRole : IdentityRole
{
    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string ProperName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

public class MyAppDb : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, string, IdentityUserLogin, IdentityUserRole, IdentityUserClaim>
{
    public MyAppDb()
        : base("MyAppDb")
    {
    }
}
```

Notice `MyAppDb` inherits from `IdentityDbContext` but that I pass an `ApplicationRole` instead of `IdentityRole`. My `ApplicationRole` inherits from `IdentityRole` so this should not be a problem.

BUT...

My `AccountController` is throwing this error:

```
The entity type IdentityRole is not part of the model for the current context.
```

At the `UserManager.CreateIdentityAsync(...)` in this code:

```
private async Task SignInAsync(ApplicationUser user, bool isPersistent)
{
     AuthenticationManager.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
     var identity = await UserManager.CreateIdentityAsync(user, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
     AuthenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties() { IsPersistent = isPersistent }, identity);
}
```

The `user` is being created here:

```
        var user = await UserManager.FindAsync(model.UserName, model.Password);
        if (user != null)
        {
            await SignInAsync(user, model.RememberMe);
            return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
        }
```

What is the "major malfunction"? ;)

**UPDATE:**
I'm fairly sure the issue has something to do with the `UserStore` here:

```
    public class AccountController : Controller
    {
        public AccountController ()
            : this(new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new MyAppDb())))
        {
        }

        public AccountController (UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
        {
            UserManager = userManager;
            UserManager.PasswordValidator = (IIdentityValidator<string>)new MinimumLengthValidator(8);
            UserManager.UserValidator = new UserValidator<ApplicationUser>(UserManager) { AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = false };
        }

        public UserManager<ApplicationUser> UserManager { get; private set; }
...
```

How do I get the `UserStore` to know about `ApplicationRole` when I can only pass it one argument?

Comment: It may be helpful to note that this project started with AspNetIdentity1.* and then was upgraded to AspNetIdentity2.0. After upgrading I extended the IdentityRole, changed the signature of MyAppDb as you can see above in my question, and the problem began.

Comment: Did your `user` have any `Roles` associated with it. If yes, show how is `user` created.

Comment: Yes.  I created the User like this:

var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);

Where "user" is an ApplicationUser. I added the User to Roles directly in the database copying a UserId from the Users table and a RoleId from the Roles table. Very straight forward.

Comment: I referred to the `ApplicationUser user`.

Comment: The `ApplicationUser user` argument that is being passed to the `SignInAsync` method, how is it created?

Comment: BTW, what version is your `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework` assembly?

Comment: I updated my question to show where {user} is being created.

Comment: Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework is 2.0. I upgraded Microsoft.AspNet.Identity using Nuget Package Manager so it automatically updated the dependencies.

Comment: You need to enclose the relevant text in backtick '`'.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I solved this issue by creating an `ApplicationUserStore` and `ApplicationUserManager`:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<string, ApplicationUserLogin, ApplicationUserRole, ApplicationUserClaim>
{
    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(ApplicationUserManager manager)
    {
        // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        // Add custom user claims here
        return userIdentity;
    }

}

public class ApplicationUserLogin : IdentityUserLogin<string>
{
}

public class ApplicationUserClaim : IdentityUserClaim<string>
{
}

public class ApplicationUserRole : IdentityUserRole<string>
{
}

public class ApplicationRole : IdentityRole<string, ApplicationUserRole>
{
    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string ProperName { get; set; }
}


public class MyAppDb : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, string, ApplicationUserLogin, ApplicationUserRole, ApplicationUserClaim>
{
    public static MyAppDb Create()
    {
        return new MyAppDb();
    }

    public MyAppDb()
        : base("MyAppDb")
    {
    }
}


public class ApplicationUserStore : UserStore<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, string, ApplicationUserLogin, ApplicationUserRole, ApplicationUserClaim>
{
    public ApplicationUserStore(MyAppDb context)
        : base(context)
    {
    }
}

public class ApplicationUserManager : UserManager<ApplicationUser, string>
{
    public ApplicationUserManager(IUserStore<ApplicationUser, string> store)
        : base(store)
    {
    }

    public static ApplicationUserManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationUserManager> options)
    {
        var manager = new ApplicationUserManager(new ApplicationUserStore(new MyAppDb()));
        // Configure the application user manager
        manager.UserValidator = new UserValidator<ApplicationUser>(manager)
        {
            AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = false,
            RequireUniqueEmail = true
        };
        manager.PasswordValidator = (IIdentityValidator<string>)new MinimumLengthValidator(8);

        return manager;
    }
}

public class ApplicationRoleStore : RoleStore<ApplicationRole, string, ApplicationUserRole>
{
    public ApplicationRoleStore(MyAppDb context)
        : base(context)
    {
    }
}

public class ApplicationRoleManager : RoleManager<ApplicationRole, string>
{
    public ApplicationRoleManager(IRoleStore<ApplicationRole, string> store)
        : base(store)
    {
    }

    public static ApplicationRoleManager Create(IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationRoleManager> options)
    {
        var manager = new ApplicationRoleManager(new ApplicationRoleStore(new MyAppDb()));

        return manager;
    }
}
```

Comment: Also worked for me, but you can use `ApplicationUserStore : UserStore<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, string, IdentityUserLogin, IdentityUserRole, IdentityUserClaim>` to save the last three derivations.