# Why is there an implementation difference between the UserStore and the RoleStore?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6, asp.net-identity

This has no problems:

```
public class ApplicationUserStore : UserStore<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, string, ApplicationUserLogin, ApplicationUserRole, ApplicationUserClaim>
{
    public ApplicationUserStore(MyAppDb context)
        : base(context)
    {
    }
}
```

While this:

```
public class ApplicationRoleStore : RoleStore<ApplicationRole, string, ApplicationUserRole>
{
    public ApplicationRoleStore(MyAppDb context)
        : base(context)
    {
    }
}
```

...produces the following compile time error:

> The type 'MyApp.Models.ApplicationRole' cannot be used as a type
>   parameter 'TRole' in the generic type or method
>   'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.RoleStore'. There is
>   no implicit reference conversion from 'MyApp.Models.ApplicationRole'
>   to 'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityRole'.

This issue came from trying to solve the issue here:
[Why is UserManager.CreateIdentityAsync() looking for IdentityRole and how to fix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22672622/why-is-usermanager-createidentityasync-looking-for-identityrole-and-how-to-fix)

I don't really care which way I solve this as long as I solve it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no issue here and **no implementation difference**. It must have been a hiccup.  A restart of Visual Studio 2013 did not resolve the compile-time error.  However, a restart of the computer did.  **No issue here--move along.**