# How to extend IdentityRole into a custom table name

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

I am trying to implement role based security to my MVC 5, Identity 2.0 project.
I have been looking at some tutorials on the internet but am a bit stuck.

I have created the following:

```
public class Role : IdentityRole
{
    public Role(string name) : base(name)
    { }

    public Role()
    { }

    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string MenuIcon { get; set; }
    public string ControllerName { get; set; }
    public string ActionName { get; set; }
}
```

and my context:

```
    new public DbSet<Role> Roles { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        //rename the tables and columns used by the Identity Framework
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>().ToTable("User");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Role>().ToTable("Role");
        modelBuilder.Entity<UserRole>().ToTable("UserRole");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>().ToTable("UserLogin");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim>().ToTable("UserClaim");
    }
```

and my Seed method:

```
    RoleManager roleManager = new RoleManager(new RoleStore<Role>(context));
    roleManager.Create<Role, string>(new Role("Orders"));
```

However when I run the application, it creates the database with 2 tables for the Roles: `Role` (which is where I want the roles to exist and it contains my custom properties) and `AspNetRoles`. It does populate both tables with the role that I created in my Seed method.

What am I doing wrong exactly that it is creating 2 tables?

Comment: I am having a similar problem. Did you finally arrive at a solution?

Answer (score 5):

All asp.net tables should recognize new table names not only the changed table.

User table:

```
public class User : IdentityUser<string, UserLogin, UserRole, UserClaim>
{
    // Your properties
}
```

UserLogin table:

```
public class UserLogin : IdentityUserLogin { }
```

UserRole table:

```
public class UserRole : IdentityUserRole { }
```

UserClaim table:

```
public class UserClaim : IdentityUserClaim { }
```

Role table: This hat to be inherited from `IdentityRole<string, UserRole>`

```
public class Role : IdentityRole<string, UserRole> 
{ 
    //Any relevant properties

    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string MenuIcon { get; set; }
    public string ControllerName { get; set; }
    public string ActionName { get; set; }    
}
```

Data context: This has to be inherited from `IdentityDbContext<User, Role, string,   UserLogin, UserRole, UserClaim>`

```
public class YourDataContext : IdentityDbContext<User, Role, string,   UserLogin, UserRole, UserClaim>
{
    // Your DbSet items

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<User>().ToTable("User");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Role>().ToTable("Role");
        modelBuilder.Entity<UserClaim>().ToTable("UserClaim");
        modelBuilder.Entity<UserLogin>().ToTable("UserLogin");
        modelBuilder.Entity<UserRole>().ToTable("UserRole");

        modelBuilder.Entity<User>().Property(r => r.Id);
        modelBuilder.Entity<UserClaim>().Property(r => r.Id);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Role>().Property(r => r.Id);

       //Add your new properties of Role table in here.


    }
}
```

In this example I have used Id of the tables as `string`type.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for that! The problem I am having is `Error 2 The type 'Express.Models.Role' cannot be used as type parameter 'TRole' in the generic type or method 'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.RoleStore<TRole>'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'Express.Models.Role' to 'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.IdentityRole'.` I also get a similar message for `User`.

Comment: I am also using identity framework 2.0, but this works for me. Make sure you correctly place two types of role tables 'UserRole' and 'Role'. Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22682017/why-is-there-an-implementation-difference-between-the-userstore-and-the-rolestor. Also check this link too https://aspnetidentity.codeplex.com/workitem/2126

Comment: Thanks! And btw you don't really have to change the table name, it is not needed, I also didnt add those `modelBuilder.Entity<User>().Property(r => r.Id);` What I did notice is a little 'bug' if you try to add properties to the AspNetRoles table, code-first migrations sometimes things it has to delete it and add it again. You can safely edit the migration and just add the columns. Oh and I also had that issue of Lock but I just had to change how to create a UserStore and Manager.

Answer (score 2):

Delete this line:

```
new public DbSet<Role> Roles { get; set; }
```

Then you have to replace the default *AspNetRoles* table columns by your own columns.

```
var applicationRole = modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationRole>().ToTable("Roles");
applicationRole.Property(r => r.Name).HasColumnName("Description");
...
```

However if you want to customize your AspNet Identity profile information could be better to create new related tables ([check this link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/10/16/customizing-profile-information-in-asp-net-identity-in-vs-2013-templates.aspx)).

Comment: Thankyou. Unfortunately, that didn't help. It did the same thing- created 2 tables with the role created in both.

Comment: @Lock Are you sure that deleting the line "new public DbSet<Role> Roles { get; set; }" the table "Role" is still beign created?

Comment: Hi there. Yes I did remove that bit.

Comment: hi, I added more properties to ASPRoles `CREATE TABLE [dbo].[AspNetRoles]
 [Id] [nvarchar](128) NOT NULL,
 [Name] [nvarchar](256) NOT NULL,
 [Description] [nvarchar](256) NOT NULL,
 [CompanyId] [nvarchar](256) NOT NULL,` now my create IdentityRole fails, how can I handle this?