# How to add custom data to ASP .NET login session

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication

I need to add some custom data to "login session". I don't know how to. Should I create some special session after login? I need to store some lists etc. 
I can add extra data to Identity claims, but only strings.

I am using ASP .NET MVC standard authentication.

```
var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
```

Comment: What kind of custom data ?

Comment: For instance List of another my class. Or just List of integers, strings etc.

Comment: does extending IdentityUser help ?

[stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22695200/744160)

Answer (score 2):

You can extend the `IdentityUser`:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
  public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
  {
     var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
     return userIdentity;
  }

  // insert the informations  that you want as new properties
     public string FullName { get; set; }
     public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
}
```

Or you can put in the session like this:

```
HttpContext context = System.Web.HttpContext.Current;
string result = context.Session["employeeInfo"]?.ToString();
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(result))
{
  ApplicationUser user = context.GetOwinContext()
        .GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>()
        .FindById(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId());
   result = _employeeAppService.GetById(user.EmployeeId);
   context.Session.Add("employeeInfo", result);
 }
```

Treat the result as you wish. Any doubts, just ask. I hope it helps.

Comment: About ApplicationUser extension.. How can I access that properties in my code (Controllers, Views)? I can use User.Identity., but I can see just standard properties or property I put into Claim (just string in this case). Thx.

Comment: If you put those new properties, they will became part of the `ApplicationUser`, as email, name etc. You will need to change the register to populate those properties.

Comment: As I don't exactly your need, I'm not able to suggest you, what I consider the better approach. But a good practice is to extend the controller class and do all these 'plumbing' there.

Comment: You can use any kind of properties, even complex user defined ones.

Comment: Check this: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/727054/ASP-NET-MVC-Identity-Extending-and-Modifying-R

Comment: PedroSouki, thanks a lot for your help. I think my description of the problem was't accurate. That's why a created a new task (URL below) and I am going to close this one. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46050910/acces-applicationuser-list-property-in-the-view-asp-net-mvc-identity-2-0