# Extend ASP .NET Identity with custom List<property> and access it in the View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, claims-based-identity, asp.net-identity-2

I am using ASP NET Identity 2.0. I need to extend the identity model with an ApplicationOrganization class (many-to-many with ApplicationUser).

So I created new class, ApplicationOrganization with;

```
public virtual ICollection<ApplicationUser> Users { get; set; }  
public virtual ICollection<ApplicationOrganization> Organizations { get; set;}
```

to ApplicationUser class to create a many-to-many relationship.

I would like to add some combo (html select tag) with available organizations into _Layout.cshtml View. That's a problem for me. In the View I can accces current UserName, UserId or any other string property using Claims. But I don't know how to acces List of ApplicationOrganization connected to User in the View. I would like to avoid creating some new login Session. And I don't want to hit database in every view call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No answer. Ok, one way I know now is I can serialize list as a string (xml, json or whatever) and store it as Identity claim. When I need it I can parse it back.